# Make javaScript/jQuery array of multiple input field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, push

Simple question i can't figure out. I'd like to make a JavaScript array of input values but can't figure out the simple code.

Here's the HTML:

```
<input class="email" value="joe@smith.com"></input>
<input class="email" value="bob@jones.com"></input>
```

Here's the not yet correct JS/jQuery which attempts to make an array:

```
$.fn.valuesArr = function()
  {
    var a = [];
    $.each(this, function(i, field){
        a.push(field.value);
    });
    return a;
  } 

var emailArr=$('.email').valuesArr();
```

Ultimately, this is what i'd like the emailArr to be:

```
emailArr= ["joe@smith.com", "bob@jones.com"];
```

Not sure what is wrong with my valuesArr function, any JS and/or jQuery-based solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems to be working to me, unless I misunderstood the question.  Here's a fiddle showing it outputting the created `emailArr`: http://jsfiddle.net/BRtDY/1/

Comment: hi Pat, you are right it does work, i didn't have the doc.ready function in my testing, frustrating! thanks for the help, best wishes, -tim

Comment: Glad to hear - you should post the answer to your question and then accept it.  It'll help anyone else that gets stuck with a similar problem to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original script was correct as Pat said. The problem was with how the script was called. The original script will work if you do either of the following:

1. making sure the original script is below the  tags in your your HTML file
2. encapsulating the script in a jQuery document.ready function, i.e., $(function(){  --$.each function() -- });

Thanks to both Pat and COLD TOLD for their help,

Answer (score 1):

This should get all the elements of class email it value and then assign it to the email array.

```
$("action").click(function () {
    var emails=new Array();
    var j=0;
    $(".email").each(function(){
        emails[j]=$(this).val();
        j++;
    });
});
```

Comment: hi COLD TOLD, thanks for your help, I followed Pat's fiddle above and made sense of it, the issue was simple, i didn't have the doc.ready $(function(){}; surrounding my valuesArr function, i'm all set now, thanks, -tim